# How to calculate percentile shares in Matlab

Tags: matlab, quantile, percentile

I have some data containing information about a variable called ``wealth".

I want to calculate the shares of those being in the top in the distribution, in the middle and in the bottom. That is how much of wealth is owned by the rich, middle, and poor.

The analogue example is to draw 10000 random variables from a gamma distribution, So suppose the distribution is this one:

```
wealth = gamrnd(shape,scale,n,1);
```

So how I can calculate how much of this variable go to say the top 10%, bottom 90% etc ...

Can someone help me  how I can do that in Matlab ?

Comment: To calculate percentiles you can use matlab's function [`prctile`](https://es.mathworks.com/help/stats/prctile.html?s_tid=gn_loc_drop). It may be of help to do what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following function, which is based on sorting your data:

```
function [ topVals, bottomVals ] = calcPercentile( x, percentile )
    sortedX = sort(x,'descend');
    m = int16(percentile*length(x));
    topVals = sortedX(1:m);
    bottomVals = sortedX(m+1:end);
end
```

Usage example:

```
%getting top 10% and bottom 90%
[ topVals, bottomVals ] = calcPercentile(x,0.1);
%getting top 40% and bottom 60%
[ topVals, bottomVals ] = calcPercentile(x,0.4);
```

Results:

```
topVals = 10
bottomVals =   9     8     7     6     5     4     3     2     1

topVals =  10     9     8     7
bottomVals =     6     5     4     3     2     1
```

Comment: This does not calculate shares though, now ? For the data of wealth I have I want to ask this type of question: what is the share of aggregate wealth that goes to the top 10%, bottom 90% etc ? So, in your example I should take the mean of the values calculate and divide with the aggregate of this vector, or no ??

Comment: You just need to replace x with wealth

Comment: Thanks. But, if I have to be more flexible to be able to see other percentile groups, like 20%, bottom 40%, I am not sure I understand exactly how I am supposed to do it.

Comment: I edited my answer, you can use the function described there

Comment: Sorry again, although I get my results correctly, there is an annoying message "Warning: Integer operands are required for colon operator when used as index" ... I can still do what I want, but I flag it out to see if your function can be further generalized.

Comment: Please take a look at my answer. It uses a built-in function which is always preferrable.

Answer (score 1):

To calculate percentiles you can use matlab's function [`prctile`](https://es.mathworks.com/help/stats/prctile.html?s_tid=gn_loc_drop). One of the ways to call the function is

```
prctile(X,p)
```

where X is your vector and p is a percentage in the range [0-100]. Note that this would be what you call "bottom percentage"

In your case, you can get the bottom n% as follows:

```
ninetyPercentBottom = prctile(X,n)
ninetyPercentBottomShare = sum(X(X<ninetyPercentBottom))/sum(X)
```

If you want the "top percentage", note that "bottom percentage" n% is the same as "top percentage" 100-n%, so you can use that idea to get the share of the top n%

```
topPercentile = 10
tenPercentTop = prctile(X,100-topPercentile)
tenPercentTopShare = sum(X(X>tenPercentTop))/sum(X)
```

Comment: notice that this requires Statistics and Machine Learning Toolbox

Comment: You need to use (..), instead of brackets [...]. Plus, I also believe that to get shares of aggregate wealth, you have to divide with  `sum(X)'. So, sum(X(X>tenPercentTop))/sum(X)..... what do you think ?

Comment: @msh855 yep. Both of your comments are right. I will edit my answer accordingly